# Обособлять ли причастный оборот?

Tags: запятые, причастный-оборот

`Всего 5(,) добравшихся до той стороны(,) продолжат участие в соревновании.`

Нужно ли обособлять, если определяемое слово *людей* убрать из предложения? Является ли *5* определяемым словом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что запятые в предложении не нужны.
*Всего пять добравшихся до той стороны продолжат участие в соревновании.*

*Пять добравшихся* — это счетный оборот, который является подлежащим.
*Добравшиеся* — это субстантивированное причастие, в обороте выполняющее роль существительного (как, например, *два командующих армиями*).

*Сделав рапорт, **пять добравшихся** до Мальты экипажей отправились в столовую* (Р. Баркер. Торпедоносцы. Британские ВВС против немецких конвоев).
***Тридцать пять добравшихся** до города стругов могли вместить не больше полутора тысяч* (А. Прозоров. Заговорщик).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего имелось:
Всего пятеро людей(,) добравшихся до той стороны(,) продолжат участие в соревновании.

Да, обособлять нужно, так как слово "пятеро", как Вы верно указали, является главным словом в данном обособленном определени. Проверить это можно двумя способами:

1. Задать вопрос от главного слова к зависимому(причастию):
   пятеро (каких?) добравшихся.
2. Убрать оборот, и посмотреть на изменившийся смысл:
   Всего пятеро людей продолжат участие в соревновании. Смысл не поменялся, значит нужно обособлять.

Comment: Я сказал, что в предложении НЕ должно быть слова _людей_! Просто _5_, и всë!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Является ли 5 определяемым словом?
```

**Да, является.** Всего пятеро — субстантивированное собирательно числительное (в значении существительного). Всего — частица, указывает на **ограниченное** количество кого-, чего-л.

***Всего пятеро*** — **определяемое слово**, к нему относится **обособленный** причастный оборот.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

Обратим внимание на разные варианты для ***ВСЕ*** и ***ВСЕГО***.

(1) *Всего пятеро, **добравшихся до той стороны**, продолжат участие в соревновании.*

(2) ***Все пятеро добравшихся до той стороны** продолжат участие в соревновании.*

**Из словаря:**

**ВСЕГО.** I. к Весь и Всё. II. местоим. нареч. Итого, в общем. В. израсходовано сто рублей. В. в отделе двадцать сотрудников. III. **ЧАСТИЦА.** Указывает на **ограниченное** количество кого-, чего-л.; не больше чем; только. Гостей будет в. четверо. До экзамена осталось в. два дня. В. в десяти шагах.

**ВЕСЬ,** всего, м.; ВСЯ, всей, ж.; ВСЁ, всего, ср.; ВСЕ, всех, вин. неодуш.: все; вин. одуш.: всех. мн.; **МЕСТОИМ. ПРИЛ.** **1. Такой**, который рассматривается в **полном объёме; целый, полный.** Отдыхать всё лето. Во всём мире. Молчать всю дорогу. Занимать весь этаж.

Answer (score 0):

У Д.Розенталя сказано, что если причастный оборот стоит после определительного, притяжательного или указательного местоимения, то он не отделяется от определяемого слова запятой. Пример: Все отобранные для выставки картины скоро будут экспонироваться.

Comment: У нас не "все", а "всего".  Как вы думаете, есть разница? Или это одно и то же?  Мне думается, что есть.